# VBA: Delete entire rows if value is duplicated for the rows below until the next different value is found and repear

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a column with true false values:

T
T
T
F
F
T
T
T
F
F
.
.
.

I want to delete rows based on the repeated values in this column such that the remaining rows will be summarised as below :

T
F
T
F
.
.
.

It will take the value i.e TRUE in the first row and iterate through each row to check for the next row that has a different value .

Since Row 1 is TRUE, and Row 4 is false, rows 2 to 3 will be deleted.

Next,it will continue by taking Row 3 value (which is FALSE) and check for the next different value (i.e.TRUE) and delete all the rows in between that.

The above process is to continue until the last row in the sheet.

Many thanks and appreciation for your help!

Comment: We will not write your code from scratch for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This will be easy to do, create a foreach loop through your range, test if value is same as cell above, and delete row if true, skip if false.

Comment: Hi I have tried using a for loop to delete the row if the value is not the same as the top... however as I have 100 000 rows, excel always ends up crashing.